# Multimedia next/previous keys don't work with Chrome

Tags: gnome, 20.04, google-chrome, chromium, multimedia

Multimedia play/pause key does work with Chrome (actually - Chromium), Gnome & Ubuntu. System volume up/down also do. But next/previous don't. How do I make them work?

I've tried setting System hotkeys in System settings window - they work the same way: play/pause, volume - work, next/prev - don't.

Ubuntu 20.04.2. Gnome 3.36.8. Chromium 88.0.4324.182 snap.

Comment: Where would you use these buttons? With Spotify? With YouTube? With Netflix? These buttons are very much site-specific in many cases, as Previous/Next would not make sense when visiting this site … 

Comment: @Matigo I've tried with youtube and music.yandex.com . And where would you suggest me to try to check if it is the problem of Ubuntu/Gnome/Chrome(-ium) or it's just a Youtube/Yandex.Music failure? (i have no accounts on spotify/netflix)